# ruby & rvm - how to install a "p" version of ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

How can I use rvm to install a specific version of Ruby, e.g. `1.9.3p327` instead of the current `1.9.3p194` that I have.

All the references and document are about the major version, e.g. `rvm install 1.9.3` but don't mention the 'p' minor version numbers.

I tried

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3p327
Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.3p327'.
Could not detect ruby version/name for installation, please be more specific.
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
$ rvm install '1.9.3p327'
Unknown ruby interpreter version: '1.9.3p327'.
Could not detect ruby version/name for installation, please be more specific.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turned out to be a dash ! `$ rvm install 1.9.3-p327`

Comment: Hmm. It does appears that the `-l` option is deprecated in the newer rvm, so I withdraw my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`rvm install 1.9.3p327` should work without single quotes.

**EDIT: The following option is now deprecated.**

Alternatly, to install a patch specific level you could use the `-l` option. For example

```
rvm install 1.9.3 -l 327
```

Comment: I would up-vote as useful but sorry, that didn't actually work for me.  `$ rvm install 1.9.3 -l 999
Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p194.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

durrantm.../durrantm$

Comment: I gave 999 as the 'l' level as a test but as you can see it's looking at my system and the 1.9.4 version (even though I have 327 installed at this point).